# Inferring geometric properties of a polytope from intersection volumes of spheres at unknown coordinates on its surface

Tags: geometry, computer-science

Let's say we have some polytope $P$ in 3-space (which is not necessarily convex) as well as some number of points on its surface, $(g_1, ..., g_N)$.  We are provided no information about the coordinates for any given point, $g_i$, or information about the underlying geometry of $P$.  However, we are able to draw a finite number of spheres of radius $(r_1, ..., r_M)$, with some $g_i$ their centerpoints, and find the volume of the intersection of each sphere with the polytope $P$.  Here, all $r_i$ are less than at least the largest cross-sectional dimension of $P$.

As a function of the number of coordinates $N$, to what extent can we learn about the geometry of $P$ using this information?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is a route to explore: Interpret your volumes as solid angles, and from
them obtain an estimate of the curvature at your points $g_i$.
Then apply the remarkable theorem of
Gluck, Krigelman, and Singer:

> "The converse to the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem in PL,"
> [*J. Diff. Geom*, 9(4): 601-616, 1974.](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-differential-geometry/volume-9/issue-4/The-converse-to-the-Gauss-Bonnet-theorem-in-PL/10.4310/jdg/1214432558.full)

which says—essentially—that given curvatures of points on a manifold $M$ that satisfy the obvious necessary
conditions, there exists a PL Riemannian metric on $M$ which realizes those curvatures
at the specified points, and is flat elsewhere.